# Collapse other element when one is opened in React JS

Tags: reactjs

[This is my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-bush-hksdg?file=/src/Compoents/ToggleComponent.jsx) in which I can toggle visibility of a div in the `ToggleComponent.jsx` file, but I want to collapse one div if other is clicked. How to achieve this??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a track of which div(section) is open by moving your state into parent component, container that holds all these divs.

```
export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => setCurrent("section1")}>Title 1</h2>
        {current === "section1" ? (
          <p>Here is the content for section 1</p>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => setCurrent("section2")}>Title 2</h2>
        {current === "section2" ? (
          <p>Here is the content for section 2</p>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => setCurrent("section3")}>Title 3</h2>
        {current === "section3" ? (
          <p>Here is the content for section 3</p>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```